# Python falcon API - internal/external python package use best practice?

Tags: python, falconframework

I have an external, stand-alone python package called 'bel' with it's own CLI scripts that uses my Falcon-based REST API for things like validating terms from a terminology store. I also use this package inside the REST API to power most of the REST API functionality.

When I try to call the API from a bel module function running inside the API instead of a stand-alone use of the bel module function, it can't access the API endpoint.

I've added a try/except clause with the following to distinguish what mode I'm running 'bel' functions in (inside or outside API service):

```
try:  # try to import API module and run call directly
    import <API module>
    ...
except ModuleNotFoundError as e:
    # call API via requests module as I'm running bel outside of API
```

Is this the right way to do this? is there a better way? I have API code polluting my stand-alone bel package code doing it this way with stronger dependencies between the two than I wanted.

I'm not even sure the best way to describe my situation which is inhibiting my ability to search for a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make a call to a Gunicorn application if you are currently in that Gunicorn application with 1 synchronous worker. It locks it up and then times out.

When running the code that was breaking using pdb, I noticed the following:

```
"timestamp": "2018-02-06T19:07:18.431785Z", "message": "WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10265)
```

My problem was the Gunicorn application was timing out when I made a REST API call to the REST API I was currently running inside of since there was only 1 synchronous worker setup for this dev box.  When I used more than 1 async worker, everything worked fine.